# Web speech API not working in updated google chrome versions

Tags: javascript, java, html

Speech to text in java not working in google chrome updated versions for example:

62.0.3202.84

working on only below 60 versions..please reply me as early as possible if you find any solution regarding this..

Comment: you can use responsiveSpeech, it works on all the versions, i did work on it recently.

Comment: responsiveSpeech means please explain clearly.